# Risk to parking pawl while loosening lug nuts with car jacked up

Tags: toyota, transmission, automatic-transmission, parking, rav4

With a car jacked up (tires is in the air), automatic transmission in park, and the emergency brake disengaged, can really cranking on lugs nuts damage a parking pawl?

---

**Scenario**

I was removing the front left tire from my 2008 Toyota RAV4.  The car was in park, the emergency brake was disengaged.  I had jacked up the car *before* loosening the lug nuts (I am a noob).  The front two tires were in the air (front part was on two jack stands), the back two tires were on the ground (held with tire wedges).

I have recently gotten new tires, and the local auto shop had cranked down on my lug nuts.  They were really tight.  To loosen them, I had to practically jump on the lug wrench to break them loose.

Do you think this could damage the parking pawl?

---

**Relevant Articles**

[Loosening lug nuts with tires off ground](https://www.subaruforester.org/threads/loosening-lug-nuts-with-tires-off-ground.218770/) hints it's possible to damage the parking pawl while doing this.

---

**My Car**

- 2008 Toyota RAV4
- Trim: Base
- Driver: 4WD
- Transmission: 4AT (automatic)

Comment: Absolutely not, unless you are the Terminator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never heard of that problem happening and I think there is now way you could "really crank" on the lug nuts more than the force of the vehicle rolling backwards on a slope when you park it.

The parking pawl is quite substantial since the parking safety of the vehicle depends on it.